# Writing into csv file with c# causes invalid format

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

I used C# for executing oracle sql queries and getting values from database after that, I need to write all the data which came from database into an excel file.I figured that out with the following code :

```
private static DataTable GetQueryResult(string query, Dictionary<string, string> parameterValues)
    {
        Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ReadConnectionString());
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        if (parameterValues != null && parameterValues.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var item in parameterValues)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
        Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            adp.Fill(tbl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {

            con.Close();

        }
        return tbl;
    }
```

I used a datatable for keeping the values.

```
DataTable queryResultTable = GetQueryResult(query, parameterValues);
        if (queryResultTable != null && queryResultTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string strHeader = GetResultHeader(queryResultTable);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(strHeader);
            SetResultRows(sb, queryResultTable);
            SaveFileDialog fg = new SaveFileDialog();
            fg.Filter = "CSV|*.csv";
            fg.Title = "Kaydedilecek dosyayi belirleyin";
            DialogResult dg = fg.ShowDialog();
            if (dg == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                File.WriteAllText(fg.FileName, sb.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254"));
            }
            if (dg == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
```

and this is the code how i write values into csv files.But sometimes the values in one column looks like invalid numbers like "2,01E+13" but it should be "20130405134559" for example.
My question is how can i stop this or is there a way for me to format some specific columns.

Comment: Do the numbers look like that in the csv file too or only when you open that file in some spreadsheet application?

Comment: They look like that in csv file too

Answer (score 0):

The number is valid, it's just in exponential form. You need to look at string formatting options in/around the call to SetResultRows.

Comment: Can you explain with an example

Comment: Take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for String formatting. I'm assuming SetResultsRows is code you haven't posted yet.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a string formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dedicated CSV library to handle this (like https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)?